# Can we get process list using sar in Ubuntu?

Tags: performance, system, process

Is able to get a processes list that runs on April 11 in the Ubuntu Server using `sar` or other tools.

Comment: I have a sar log file for the date of April 11 using that I need to get the list of processes (applications)  that run during that date. @David

Comment: The question is perfectly clear, and unfortunately the answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not how `sar` (system activity report) works. The [sar manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/sar.sysstat.1.html) details the possible options.

Common options are CPU, memory, network, I/O stats etc. But `sar` does not contain any information about which processes were running at a given time.

For detailed process information, you have to do some other kind of monitoring - for instance a script that takes a snapshot of `ps aux` every 10 minutes.

Comment: I'd add that the correct way to collect this type of data is to enable & configure auditd, and appropriately manage the audit logs.

Comment: @AndyC Or possibly leverage the kernel’s process accounting infrastructure, depending on exactly what data is desired.